# My query is giving following error,Unexpected token WHERE

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

i'm working in java with sql.when ever this query is executed it gives me the error mentioned in title

```
      try(PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO student_signup(q" + strId + ")" + "WHERE student_email="+email+"VALUES(?)")) {
        statement.setString(1, SelectedOption);

        statement.executeUpdate();


    statement.close();
```

for a little code background 
here

```
  int questionID=1;
  String strId = Integer.toString(questionID);
  String email = signInForm.getTxtEmail().getText();
```

Comment: You are missing a space before the `WHERE` and the `VALUES` .

Comment: so its just a space issue ? i mean is query alright ?

Comment: Which "INSERT" command expects a "WHERE" clause?

Comment: `INSERT` with `WHERE`?

Comment: @newprogrammer : No it still isn't, have a look at the answers below .

Comment: Use a prepared statement for this. This query allows SQL injection.

Comment: i am actually using prepared statement @Compass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INSERT` inserts new rows.  I think you want to change a value in an existing row.  For that, use `UPDATE`.  Something like this:

```
UPDATE student_signup
    SET strID = ?
    WHERE student_email = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT is never use with WHERE clause
If you want to change the value for a pre-existing record in the database, you should try the UPDATE clause with WHERE condition after it.